# Compiler error with complement operator

Tags: c#

I'm using the logical AND `&=` and complement `~` operators and getting a strange compiler error.

```
// Constants
private const byte XML_MATCH_ID         = 0x01;
private const byte XML_MATCH_MAC        = 0x02;
private const byte XML_MATCH_DEFAULT    = (XML_MATCH_ID + XML_MATCH_MAC);

// ...
byte matchingTags = XML_MATCH_DEFAULT;
// ... (reading XML nodes)

// Assume Machine ID doesn't match
matchingTags &= (byte)~XML_MATCH_ID;    // Compiler error: Constant value '-2' cannot be converted to a 'byte'

// Assume MAC Address doesn't match
matchingTags &= (byte)~XML_MATCH_MAC;   // Same compiler error but with "-3"
```

When I change the first statement above to the following equivalent statement it all works fine.

```
matchingTags &= (0xff - XML_MATCH_ID);
```

Why is the compiler throwing this error?

Comment: IF it's c# then use the unchecked keyword: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx

Comment: The error message says "use unchecked syntax to override".  Why are you not using the unchecked syntax to override the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler seems to be trying to compile the compliment as a constant.
The compiler error I get is "Overflow in constant value computation"

Which is not really that strange. `byte` is a [Unsigned 8-bit integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx). (If you are looking for a [Signed 8-bit integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d86he86x.aspx), then you should use `sbyte`)

`~XML_MATCH_ID` returns an `int` of value `-2`, which is not castable into a `byte (uint8)`.

One way to work around this is to store the `~XML_MATCH_ID` as a temporary `int` variable, and then do the logical AND:

```
int temp = ~XML_MATCH_ID;  // temp now holds the value "-2"
byte temp2 = (byte)temp;   // temp2 now holds the value "254"
matchingTags &= temp2;
```

or avoid using the complement operator at all:

```
matchingTags &= (byte.MaxValue - XML_MATCH_ID);
```

Comment: To me this compiler warning is unexpected. `XML_MATCH_ID` is an unsigned 8-bit integer, so inverting all its bits using the complement operator should result in another unsigned 8-bit integer. Your suggestion to avoid using the complement operator here is a sensible.

Comment: @AlainD: Your logic is unfortunately specious. C# does not have the rule that the type of the result of an operator is the same as the type of its operands. Rather, C# uses overload resolution to choose from a number of built-in operators, and there is no built-in negation operator that takes a byte. In this case the C# compiler will choose the one that takes an int, and so the result is an int.

Comment: @bendik: Though this answer is correct in that it produces the right result, it would be more idiomatic to do what the error message already tells the user to do, which the user has mysteriously not done: **use the unchecked syntax to override the error reporting**.

Comment: @EricLippert: I was not aware of that, so thanks. Given that information the compiler error is not so mysterious! Bendiks' suggestion to avoid the complement operator (and `unchecked`) in this context seems to me to be easier to read and therefore the more appropriate option.